# fsck: error 2 (No such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext4, fsck exited with status code 8

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, filesystems

I'm getting this error every time I boot:

> fsck: error 2 (No such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext4 for /dev/sda1
>
> fsck exited with status code 8

My `sda` drive is a ~250 GB SSD, and I also have a ~1 Tb HDD in `sdb`:

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA KINGSTON SUV300S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:
 
Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  231GB  231GB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      231GB   240GB  8565MB  extended
 5      231GB   240GB  8565MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 
 
Model: ATA WDC WD10EZEX-75Z (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:
 
Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ext4
```

I've tried the steps outlined [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2353957) which resulted in:

```
$ sudo swapoff -a
$ sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/sda1
                                                                               
     1469617 inodes used (10.40%, out of 14131200)
        4584 non-contiguous files (0.3%)
        1287 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 1389334/471/1
    31572826 blocks used (55.87%, out of 56516096)
           0 bad blocks
           1 large file
 
     1206890 regular files
      176663 directories
          56 character device files
          25 block device files
           1 fifo
      371867 links
       85950 symbolic links (79698 fast symbolic links)
          23 sockets
------------
     1841475 files

$ sudo e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sda1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
 
     1469617 inodes used (10.40%, out of 14131200)
        4584 non-contiguous files (0.3%)
        1287 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 1389334/471/1
    31572826 blocks used (55.87%, out of 56516096)
           0 bad blocks
           1 large file
 
     1206890 regular files
      176663 directories
          56 character device files
          25 block device files
           1 fifo
      371867 links
       85950 symbolic links (79698 fast symbolic links)
          23 sockets
------------
     1841475 files
```

but the error still shows. I've read that this could be related to the `fstab` file, which looks like:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>                             <mount point>   <type>          <options>          <dump>  <pass>
UUID=ffc2658d-c534-4681-b546-f8a15a7d982f   /               noatime,ext4    errors=remount-ro  0       1
UUID=4291b58b-c67b-4068-9669-3aec74d5fbbc   none            swap            sw                 0       0
UUID=64fb902c-ff42-4649-b557-413d3156e20f   /media/rest     ext4            defaults           0       0
```

I checked the `UUID`s but they seem fine:

```
$ sudo blkid             
/dev/sda1: UUID="ffc2658d-c534-4681-b546-f8a15a7d982f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="08c4ed9a-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="4291b58b-c67b-4068-9669-3aec74d5fbbc" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="08c4ed9a-05"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="rest" UUID="64fb902c-ff42-4649-b557-413d3156e20f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0004fdb0-01"
```

What is going on here? Is my SSD drive failing?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, but with a HDD 500, I type `fsck /dev/sda1` and this fixed some nodes errors on my HDD and after reboot, have some errors but started.

Then I rebooted it again and it works normally.

It can be the same problem.

Good luck to you!